# HQL Query SELECT with NOT IN

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I need a HQL Query but I just dont get it.

```
SELECT * FROM Poll WHERE pid NOT IN (
SELECT pid FROM votes WHERE uid =  'theuserid')
```

I want all List of Poll´s back where the uid **not in** the table votes exists.

Also helpfull would be the hql query where the uid **in** the table votes exists, but I guess this is very similar ;-)

These are the 2 classes:

```
public class Poll {

private int pid;
private String name;
private String description;
private Date deadline;
private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<Team>(0);
//some getter & setter
}

public class Vote {

private int vid;
private String uid;
private int pid;
private int tid;
private int votes;
//some getter & setter
}
```

Can smbdy please help me. I guess it is a join with a WHERE and NOT LIKE but I just dont get it.

Merci!

This is btw the hibernate mapping:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="package.model.Poll" table="poll">
 <id name="pid" column="pid" >
 <generator class="increment"/>
 </id>
<property name="name" column="name" />
<property name="description" column="description" />
<property name="deadline" type="timestamp" column="deadline" />

<set name="teams" table="pollchoice" 
        inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="knt.exceedvote.model.Team">
            <column name="tid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many> 
</set>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping> 

 <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="package.model.Vote" table="votes">
    <id name="vid" column="vid" >
    <generator class="increment"/>
   </id>
<property name="pid" column="pid" />
<property name="uid" column="uid" />
<property name="tid" column="tid" />
<property name="votes" column="votes" />


  </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: The query you wrote should have worked. If it doesn't what does it show now

Comment: Can you try this? 

`SELECT * FROM poll p LEFT JOIN votes v on p.pid = v.pid `
`WHERE v.uid <> 'theuserid' `

Comment: @polin u are right just have to modify in hql ;) This works:
    SELECT p FROM Poll p WHERE p.pid NOT IN (SELECT v.pid FROM Vote v WHERE v.uid =  '123')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind, **Hibernate is designed using the notion of `Object Graph`**, which is a name given to the **relational objects.**

That core concept is missing in your mapping (Poll and Vote seem to be isolated) hence I doubt you can use `HQL` in its current state.

In my opinion, you have two options:

1. Define the relationship between `Poll`, `pid` and `Vote`, `uid`. Then you should be able to write simple `HQL`.
2. Use native SQL through `Hibernate` session itself.

Comment: Thanks this was the hint I needed:
So it is working:
        SELECT p FROM Poll p WHERE p.pid NOT IN (SELECT v.pid FROM Vote v WHERE v.uid =  '123')